# How to acces asp label controls from external stylesheets

Tags: asp.net, label, stylesheet, external

I was trying to style asp Label  controls from external StyleSheet.

To my surprise, unlike `img`, `input[type='text']`, `input[type='button']` etc that works on asp image, textbox, button controls respectively,

the styles are not being applied to the label controls..!

how is asp label rendered as html?

Does anyone know how to refer to all label controls from external style sheets, other than manually specifying a css class for each of them or using inline styles...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean ASP.NET not Classic ASP, right?

**asp:Label** controls get rendered differently depending on whether they have **AssociatedControlID** set or not.

If AssociatedControlID is set they get rendered as a **label** HTML element.

If AssociatedControlID is not set they get rendered as a **span** HTML element.

It is good practice for accessibility and other reasons to always include an AssociatedControlID if the label control relates to an input control.

Comment: Thanks.. that solved the problem... in my case it was being rendered as SPAN element, i thought it was being rendered as label..!